# How to disable fancybox quick view magento

Tags: magento

I bought "Megashop - Responsive Magento Theme" from Themeforest and I want to disable the "quick view" for "add to cart", but I don't know where to look. There is no extension in the backend of magento. The code snippet says:

```
<div class="product_icons">
<button type="button" title="add to cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="showOptions('6')">
<span>
</button>
<a href="http://xxx.xx/ajax/index/options/product_id/6/" class="fancybox quick_view quick_box6" id="fancybox6">quick view</a>
```

Where do I have to look for the snippet to disable the fancybox for "add to cart"?

Thanx for your help!

Comment: I cant access this thing so I just suggest you hide using with css ,add css .quickllook{display:none}

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to do it through enable/disable system config setting from backend then you should create you own config setting first. You can find system.xml in you module directory of this theme and add your setting. you can follow this tutorial to create custom system config setting http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration .
Then in your code

```
<div class="product_icons">
<button type="button" title="add to cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="showOptions('6')">
<span>
</button>
<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('theme_module/quickview/active')): ?>
<a href="http://xxx.xx/ajax/index/options/product_id/6/" class="fancybox quick_view quick_box6" id="fancybox6">quick view</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In case you don't have any module available for theme settings, then you will need to create a small module following above link.